# Time series data excel import with a fixed freq = 52 for every year(irrespective of leap year) in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-import

I am generating the week numbers for a period of 5 consecutive years
I need a fixed week number 52 for each year.
Now I am having a 53rd-week number in 2016.
Is there a way to fix the week numbers to 52 for all the years in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
week_date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2014', periods = 299, freq = 'w')
```